# Install xcode 4.4 and xcode 4.5 side by side?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Is this even possible? I can't seem to find any resources on the internet about this. I've been seeing threads about having it installed side by side.. but am not sure if that works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. XCode 4.5 DP Preview is a stand-alone application that doesn't substitute the actual XCode (4.4).

I just installed it yesterday and they work good together!

Of course you have to open XCode 4.5 if you want to test the app with iOS 6 Simulator, otherwise, with XCode 4.4

Comment: To elaborate on this, you just mount the 4.5.dmg, and drag it to your Applications folder. The newer Xcodes are thankfully just regular applications now.

Comment: Yes, indeed! But am i the only one who's experiencing some problems with the iOS 6 Simulator?

Comment: nope. I think most developers are, due to the high adoption rates that iOS has. Unlike Android, there are no limitations or reasons to stay on older versions. Plus there are usually major new apis and features.

Comment: I mean, i run my app in Simulator, i close it, i try to relaunch it in Simulator and the simulator stays black. Hope they will fix it

Comment: @Ah, I read to experimenting. Perhaps you meant experiencing? Regardless, My team and I have had zero issues with the Simulator.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, my bad. Well i'll try to re-download an replace XCode 4.5 and see if something changes. Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure you can. I use the Xcode 4.5 DP because Xcode 4.4's ios simulator have problems with twitter

Answer (score 1):

YES, as the documentation implies.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004635-SW1

> **Xcode 4.5 can coexist on a Mac with previous versions of Xcode.**

under **Installation** section

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has moved to the standalone application model. This allows you to run both applications on your system side-by-side with little to no conflicts.

That being said, I have noticed some issues running in this setup. They may or may not be dealbreakers, but something to be aware of.

- When running 4.5 Beta simulator and you switch back to 4.4 (5.1 Simulator) it will crash or hang your simulator (6.0). Be sure to close the iOS Simulator when switching back and forth as they they can't run side by side and are separate applications.
- Be careful you don't use any API's/methods/literals that aren't available in 4.4. I think most things are safe, but something to be aware of if you are testing applications in both environments.

For the most part, everything works great when run side-by-side. It isn't advertised much, but that is probably because most beta stuff is under NDA and doesn't get discussed much. I don't see the harm in discussing a side by side setup. Good luck.